# PHP - Protect PDF file being access by direct link

Tags: php, pdf

I have a PDF file in my server, and there is a PHP page to force download the PDF file after some credential validation such as password validation, but if the user able to know the direct link of the PDF file they manage to view/download it without go through the credential validation.

Is there any method to protect the PDF file being access via direct link like http://domain.com/mypdf.pdf?

Comment: HTTP Basic Auth? What have you tried?

Comment: use .htaccess on the folder where you keep your files. a .htaccess can deny all direct requests.

Comment: @Salar Can you write the htaccess code here that able to block all access from direct link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this code...

The best way would be to protect that folder with `htaccess`, as you have mentioned. So you put all PDFs in `pdf/` folder, and in the same `pdf` folder you put `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* your-php-script.php
```

Now no files can be accessed by url in this folder. Every request to a file in this folder will return what `your-php-script.php` script returns. In `your-php-script.php` you do something like this:-

```
//Check if user has right to access the file. If no, show access denied and exit the script.
$path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$paths = explode('/', path);
$lastIndex = count($paths) - 1;
$fileName = $paths[$lastIndex]; // Maybe add some code to detect subfolder if you have them
// Check if that file exists, if no show some error message
// Output headers here
readfile($filename);
```

Comment: I've not tried this but would it not result in unreadable "garbage" if you don't set the correct HTTP header for the filetype you're spaffing out with `readfile()` ? Or would the browser create a *download file* dialogue box?

Comment: I wasn't really questioning the security model - simply that if you print a PDF to the output buffer without first telling it that it's a PDF ( `header('Content-Type' ...` ) ... what happens?

Comment: Ok. then you can add it in your code. then it would not make any problem

Comment: Ok I understand the logic mentioned above, thanks for the sharing.
What if without PHP readfile? let's said I have a html page which contained <a> link to download the PDF file, and I wish to authorize only this HTML file to access the PDF file, is it possible to do that?

<a href="http://domain.com/mypdf.pdf" download>

Comment: Yes. Pass the tokens and key values also in the url like `<a href="domain.com/mypdf.pdf?tokens=your_key&key_values=your_keyvalues">`...